# Prove $E[f(X,Y)\mid Y]=E[f(X,Y)\mid Y,Z]$ if $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

I would like to prove the following claim (which I think is true):

Suppose $\mathcal{F}_1 \subset \mathcal{F}_2$ are two $\sigma$-fields, $X,Y$ are random variables, and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function. If $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_2$, $Y\in\mathcal{F}_1$, then $E[f(X,Y)\mid \mathcal{F}_1] = E[f(X,Y)\mid \mathcal{F}_2]$.

Intuitively, this is just saying $E[f(X,Y)\mid Y]=E[f(X,Y)\mid Y,Z]$ if $X$ is independent of the pair $(Y,Z)$, but I don't know how to prove the above claim rigorously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proposed "intuitive" version should say $X$ is independent of the pair $(Y,Z),$ not just that $X$ is independent of each of them. For example, if $Y,Z\sim \operatorname{i.i.d.} \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $Z$ is the mod-$2$ sum of $Y$ and $Z,$ then $X$ is independent of each of $Y$ and $Z$ but $X$ is not independent of the pair $(Y,Z). \qquad$

Comment: An approximation argument will work: first note that when $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$, we have $E[f(X,Y)∣\mathcal{F}_1]=E[g(X)h(Y)∣\mathcal{F}_1]=h(Y)E[g(X)] $ because $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_1$-measurable. Similarly $E[f(X,Y)∣\mathcal{F}_2]=E[g(X)h(Y)∣\mathcal{F}_2]=h(Y)E[g(X)]$. Now approximate $f$ by functions of the form $f_n:=g_1h_1+⋯+g_nh_n$, where for each $n\geq 1$, $|f_n(X,Y)| \leq Z$ for some $L^1(\Omega, P)$-integrable $Z$. (you can take g, h to be elementary functions). Use DCT to conclude.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for pointing this out. I've added this to the question.

Comment: @Sayantan Thanks for your answer, but could you say more about how to construct $f_n, g_n$?

Comment: @user548641The $f_n$ and $g_n$'s that I had in mind are just indicators. Recall that there are stages by which one approximates an arbitrary measurable function $f$: first by elementary functions, then by simple functions, by bounded measurable functions and so on. By definition an elementary function is an indicator of a Borel set, so in our present setting one can take rectangles (of the form $A\times B$) instead of an arbitrary Borel set. The indicator of rectangles can easily be seen to have the form $f_n g_n$. In the next step construct simple functions as linear sums of  such indicators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be an element of $\mathcal F_2$. Since $X$ is independent of $\mathcal F_2$, we have
$$\tag{*}     \mathbb E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right]=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb E\left[f\left(x,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right]  \mathrm dP_X(x)         $$
and for all real number $x$, $\mathbb E\left[f\left(x,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right] =\mathbb E\left[f\left(x,Y\right)\mathbb E\left[   \mathbf 1_F   \mid \mathcal F_1  \right]\right]  $ hence 
$$\mathbb E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right]=\mathbb E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mathbb E\left[   \mathbf 1_F   \mid \mathcal F_1  \right]  \right] .$$
Let $Z:=f\left(X,Y\right)$. Since 
$$\mathbb E\left[Z\mathbb E\left[   \mathbf 1_F   \mid \mathcal F_1  \right] \mid\mathcal F_1    \right]= \mathbb E\left[   \mathbf 1_F   \mid \mathcal F_1  \right]\mathbb E\left[Z \mid\mathcal F_1    \right]= \mathbb E\left[ \mathbf 1_F \mathbb E\left[  Z  \mid \mathcal F_1  \right] \mid\mathcal F_1    \right],    $$
we have 
$$\mathbb E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mathbb E\left[   \mathbf 1_F   \mid \mathcal F_1  \right]  \right]=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[   f\left(X,Y\right)\mid\mathcal F_1  \right]    \mathbf 1_F      \right].$$
We showed that for all $F\in\mathcal F_2$,
$$
\mathbb E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right]=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[   f\left(X,Y\right)\mid\mathcal F_1  \right]    \mathbf 1_F      \right],
$$
which is what we wanted.

**Proof of (*):** we use the following fact: if $X$ is independent of a vector $(V_1,V_2)$, then for any function $g\colon \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$, 
$$\mathbb E\left[g \left(X,V_1,V_2\right) \right]  =\int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb E\left[g\left(x,V_1,V_2\right)  \right]  \mathrm dP_X(x),$$
which follows from an application of Fubini's theorem and the fact that the law of $    \left(X,V_1,V_2\right)$ is the product measure between the laws of $X$ and $\left(V_1,V_2\right)$. We then apply this to $V_1=Y$, $V_2=\mathbf 1_F$ and $g \colon (x,v_1,v_2) \mapsto f(x,v_1)v_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you say more about why $\mathbb E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right]=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb E\left[f\left(x,Y\right)\mathbf 1_F   \right]  \mathrm dP_X(x)$ and where you use the independence in this step?

Comment: I have edited.${}$

Comment: The question is ill-posted due to integrability issue. To talk about conditional expectation, $f(X,Y)$ must be an integrable random variable.